# How do I use pony.vim

Tags: python, django, vim

I have installed [pony.vim](https://github.com/rainerborene/vim-pony)

I cannot find any documentation to read on how to use it. I installed it via vundle [gmarik vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle)

if I type any of these I don't get any help either

```
:helptags pony
:helptags pony-vim
```

is anyone using it and can assist?

Comment: `:helptags` won’t ever show you any help. You have to use `:help pony` after `:helptags /path/to/directory` (vundle is stated to regenerate it automatically, so you don’t need to bother). Current helptags calls are invalid in any case. And, yes, `:help` won’t show you anything if plugin lacks documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The plugin has zero documentation. That's *bad.*

Did you [look at the code](https://github.com/rainerborene/vim-pony/blob/master/plugin/pony.vim#L60-65)?

The commands available seem to be:

```
:Dadmin
:Dmodels
:Dtests
:Dviews
:Durls
:Dmanage
```

From what I understand, you should be able to do something like the following to navigate to a model:

```
:Dmodels <Tab>
```

Comment: It would also be worth creating a ticket on it's [issue tracker](https://github.com/rainerborene/vim-pony/issues) requesting some basic docs (even just a few lines in the readme)

Comment: Zero documentation.  It's not worth messing with unless someone more astute than I can tell us how to use this plugin.